# IOT Central Offline Messaging

Tags: javascript, iot, azure-iot-central

How I can handle the offline scenarios while sending messages from IOT device(not an IOT Edge) to IOT Central. My device may get diconnected from network but I need to store the messages locally and sync when it's back online. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IoT Central App feature for [uploading file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-configure-file-uploads) when the device is a back to online.
Uploaded blob will generate an event message for Azure Event Grid subscriber for handling your needs.

Comment: But If I follow this I couldn't view the data in IOT Central dashboards right?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need to see the data as telemetry in IoT Central, you need to implement own store and forward logic at the device end. But as @Roman Kiss suggested larger set of data is preferred to be uploaded as a file, custom dashboard can be added via PowerBI or your own visualization linked to IoT Central. e.g. https://github.com/iot-for-all/iiot-oee